# Spring security multiple hasIPAddress antMatchers

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have the following spring security configuration snippet:

```
http
   .authorizeRequests()
   .antMatchers("/tokens").hasIpAddress("10.0.0.0/16")
   ....
```

This works, but I would also like to grant access to `"/tokens"` from `127.0.0.1`. I was hoping something along the lines of the following would work, but it doesn't:

```
http
   .authorizeRequests()
   .antMatchers("/tokens").hasIpAddress("10.0.0.0/16").hasIpAddress("127.0.0.1/32")
   ....
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/tokens").access(
            "hasIpAddress('10.0.0.0/16') or hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1/32')")
....
```

Comment: please share complete method definition of configure method.

Comment: Ugly but working... obviously the people designing the floating api only had the happy paths in mind...  THX!

Comment: how to do it in spring security 6

Answer (score 4):

Try to set this configuration in the spring security configuration file like this

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
<intercept-url pattern="/tokens**" access="hasIpAddress('10.0.0.0/16') or hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1/32')" />
</http>
```

Answer (score 0):

for spring security 6 i think this should work:

```
http
.authorizeHttpRequests()
.requestMatchers("/token/**")
.access((authentication, context) -> 
new AuthorizationDecision(new IpAddressMatcher("10.0.0.0/16").matches(context.getRequest())));

return http.build();
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**