# Spring boot security config with Docker

Tags: java, spring, docker

I have a running microservice that allow access from specific IP addresses. I am using hasIpAddress in the SpringConfiguration class to restrict access to a list of IP.

I pushed the app in Docker container and now I'm trying to access the services, as before but now I've got 403 access denied.  I suspect that I need to add the Docker container Ip address to the hasIpAddress list, but I won't know this address until the container is built.

I tried to see if I can use the full URL path of the Docker container in the SpringConfiguration class but this does not see to work.

I am wondering if this feasible, and if not I would appreciate any suggestions how to accomplish this task. and example or pointer to an example would be a great help.

Comment: What IP address are you getting in `hasIpAddress`?

Comment: hasIpAddress is generally used like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28303097/spring-security-multiple-hasipaddress-antmatchers.   I provide a list of Ip addresses that I want the app to let in.

Answer (score 1):

`hasIpAddress('xxx')` use `request.getRemoteAddress()` as IP

You can check `request.getRemoteAddress()`