# Spring Boot - FilterRegistrationBean setAllow() for several ip addresses

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

How would one set `setAllow()` ( = grant ip access my webserver) for 2 or more ip addresses?

This works flawlessly for one address :

```
  @Bean
  public FilterRegistrationBean remoteAddressFilter() {
    FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    RemoteAddrFilter filter = new RemoteAddrFilter();
    filter.setAllow("127\\.0\\.0\\.1");
    filter.setDenyStatus(403);
    filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(filter);
    filterRegistrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    return filterRegistrationBean;
  }
```

I was thinking of a whitelist properties file that I would preload into my filter bean but I could not find a suitable implementation on the web.

I don't use any `.xml` files for my configuration. If your solution implies creating a `web.xml` please elaborate on **how to create**, **where to put** and **how to call**.

P.S : ***New to Spring / Spring Boot and Security configuration setups***

Thank you.

Comment: `.antMatchers("/").access("hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1') or hasIpAddress('xxx.xx.xx.x1') or hasIpAddress('xxx.xx.xx.x2')  ")` and so on. Just or `or` or `||` in the `access` expression.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring security multiple hasIPAddress antMatchers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28303097/spring-security-multiple-hasipaddress-antmatchers)

Comment: nope not a duplicate, my question points to FilterRegistrationBean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just separate them via `|` e.g. `127\\.0\\.0\\.1|192\\.168\\.0\\.1` it's just a plain regex value.